# Create Jar file which references another jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I used Eclipse Europa to develop my code . I am able to execute my code using eclipse. However i would like export my code as jar .

I have 4 classes in my project. I have used default package. 
My Class references external jars .

I tried to export as jar using export jar option . I donot have runnable jar option .

When i try to execute the program in command line it says

```
java -jar rus.jar "F2ile.xls" "Links.txt"

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/us
rmodel/RichTextString
        at ReadText.main(ReadText.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTe
tString
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Consider reading [Adding Classes to your JAR's Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: I am building jar using Eclipse. Not sure how to specify classpath

Comment: [Eclipse Europa](https://www.eclipse.org/europa/) was released in 2007. [Eclipse Luna](https://www.eclipse.org/luna/) was released in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classpath issue, you can try the following:

```
java -cp rus.jar:<poi-*.jar> <class> //poi jar name to provide and the class
```

Other option would be to use manifest file:

```
<jar jarfile="rus.jar">
    ..
    ..
    <manifest>
       <attribute name="Main-Class" value="<class_name>"/>
       <attribute name="Class-Path" value="<poi*.jar>"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Package your jar with a MANIFEST file in the META-INF directory (at root level in the jar file).
In the MANIFEST add an entry to specify the main class to execute:
 `Main-Class: classname`
where classname is the full class name including the package.
When packaged you can run the main class with the command `java -jar jarfile.jar`. 
You do not have to specify the class name on the command line. Easier for anybody that could use your jar file.